# Reduce number of decimals but keep the power in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to reduce the decimals of a number but keep its power, to show it in a Matplotlib legend.

For example : `8.959976109870809e-10` -> `8.95998e-10`

Currently, the code I want to modify is : `plt.plot(x, y, label = f"a{i}={slope};b{i}={intercept}")`

(slope and intercept are the parameters of a linear regression)

Is there any way to do it ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string formatting to determine the precision of your number, then you can simply add this formatted string to your plot label

```py
formatted = '{:.5e}'.format(8.959976109870809e-10)
```

Or, using f-strings

```py
num = 8.959976109870809e-10
formatted = f'{num:.5e}'
```

Answer (score 0):

convert you number to string then use Decimal, this is the example

```
from decimal import Decimal

stringNumber = '8.959976109870809e-10'

print('%.5E' % Decimal(stringNumber))
```

or you can do something like this

```
from decimal import Decimal

print('%.5E' % Decimal(str(8.959976109870809e-10)))
```

> output: 8.95998E-10